# Query returns different number of rows when used in an SSRS report

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, reporting-services

My query returns 6 rows when run on production server. But when the same query is used to build SSRS report, it returns only the first 2 rows of the data when run in production. I have been trying to get the issue sorted for 2 days now. Any help is appreciated!

Here's the query:

```
declare @StartDate varchar(255), declare @EndDate varchar(255)

select I.CustomerIdName AS 'Customer Name', COUNT(S.[Subject]) AS'Activities' 
from dbo.Incident I 
FULL OUTER JOIN 
dbo.ServiceAppointment S
on I.IncidentId = S.RegardingObjectId 
FULL OUTER JOIN
dbo.Account A
on A.AccountId = I.AccountId
JOIN
FilteredAccount AS CRMAF_FilteredAccount ON CRMAF_FilteredAccount.accountid = I.CustomerId
WHERE I.CustomerIdName IS NOT NULL 
AND (S.ScheduledStart BETWEEN CAST(@StartDate AS datetime) AND CAST(@EndDate as datetime)) 
GROUP BY I.CustomerIdName,A.OwnerIdYomiName
```

Comment: pleae add your query, and sample data if you can

Comment: Are you sure your datasource used by your report is connected to the production database?

Comment: If you want some help you need to provide a lot more detail about your problem such as code, details of report design and data source.

Comment: Have you used SQL Profiler to see if SSRS is really executing exactly the same query?

Comment: Maybe its a connection problem. But I am going to use SQL Profiler to check on the query. Thanks! I will get back on this.

Comment: I ran a trace and found out that there was a mismatch with pre-filtering. CRM automatically substitutes a date range while running the FilteredAccount view. I put in a LEFT JOIN which is not the best practice but it'll have to do for now until I find out more. Thank you Pondlife!

Answer (score 1):

Couple of things to check.

- Filters : Check your SSRS table for filters you may have placed on
- Cached data : Go to the root of your solution and delete any .data files and re-rubn your report
- Connections : You mention you have production? Logic dictates you have a Dev. Check your data-sources are point the right way.

Comment: The problem was with pre-filtering. The FilteredAccount function was automatically substituting a date range. I went the ugly route by using LEFT JOIN against this function. LEFT JOIN
FilteredAccount AS CRMAF_FilteredAccount ON CRMAF_FilteredAccount.accountid = I.CustomerId

Comment: Now it works fine. I found this out after running a trace. SSRS and CRM is really funny that way! Thanks everybody for all your help!